# Not working Server side rendering Styled-Components with Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components, server-side-rendering

I tried to solve my problem through code and debug, but I couldn't figure out the cause, so I posted a question, and attached _document.js and _app.js and babel contents.

In addition applied disable Javasrcipt in Chrome.

If you have more information, please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**network**

[image]

**debugger**

[image]

**babel**

```
    {
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components",
      {
        "fileName": true,
        "displayName": true,
        "pure": true,
        "ssr": true,
        "preprocess": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**_document.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {

        const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
        const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
        try {
            ctx.renderPage = () =>
                originalRenderPage({
                    enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
                        sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
                });
            
            const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

            return {
                ...initialProps,
                styles: (
                    <>
                        {initialProps.styles}
                        {sheet.getStyleElement()}
                    </>
                ),
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            sheet.seal();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head />
                <body>
                    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default%2Ces2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Ces2018%2Ces2019"></script>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Prototype from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

import wrapper from '../store/configureStore';

const App = ({ Component }) => {

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <meta charSet='utf-8'></meta>
                <title>NodeBird</title>
            </Head>
            <Component />
        </>

    );
}

App.Prototype = {
    Component: Prototype.elementType.isRequired,
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(App);
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your `styled-components` setup. The error seems to originate from the `antd` library, though. Where are you using `antd`?

Comment: @juliomalves
`Antd` is imported from `_app.js `
And I read other issues, and `Antd` saw that SSR can be checked after deployment.


The `styled component` itself seems to have no problem with SSR.
I checked by configuring the pages separately.

Answer (score 2):

### Install

npm  i  babel-plugin-styled-components  --save-dev

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
   [
     "styled-components",
     {
        "ssr": true,
        "displayName": true,
        "preprocess": false
      }
   ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).